# How to plot a straight segment of a first degree function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tkz-fct

I need to plot the following function (just like in the image) but I do not know how to use the features of the TKZ package and the PGFPLOTS:

[image]

The most I could get close to the image was with:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    minor tick num=1,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=25,
    ymin=490, ymax=540,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
\addplot[blue,domain=-5:25] {2*x+500};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So, how can i do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
   \draw[thick,->] (0,-1) -- (0,5);
   \draw[thick,->] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[right]{$x$};
   \draw (0,3) node[left]{$500$} -- (4,3.8);
   \draw[dashed,thick] (2,0) node[below] {$10$} |- (0,3.4) node[left]{$520$};
   \node[below left] {$0$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @marmot!

I followed his guidance and was able to adapt as I needed. Thanks again, because now I understand the code.

Here's what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[thick,->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[left]{C$(x)$};
\draw[thick,->] (-0.5,0) -- (3,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw (0,1.8) node[,left]{$500$} -- (2.5,2.55);
\draw[dashed,thick] (1.5,0) node[below] {$10$} |- (0,2.25) node[left]{$520$};
\node[below left] {$0$};
\fill[black] (1.5,2.25) circle (1.4pt) node[right]{\empty};
\fill[black] (0,1.8) circle (1.4pt) node[right]{\empty};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Thanks a lot for the help. Problem solved.